# Spring 2.5 remember-me

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, filter

I need to create a "keep me signed-in" functionality, my application is currently using spring 2.5, I checked it on :
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html#remember-me-persistent-token
which tells about the `remember-me` tag which does it part, I also tried extending `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` but I'm unable to get through.
Can someone please guide me to the solution for the requirement.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Vaibhav

Comment: And what is wrong with Spring Security's build in one?! Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: with spring 3.0 it is an in built one i am not sure if something like that exists for spring 2.5

Comment: It has nothing to do with Spring but Spring Security! Spring != Spring Security. And if I'm not mistaken Remember Me functionality has been part of Spring Security since 2.0.

Comment: Probably its something to account for my lack of knowledge on the subject. Can you give me some pointers for same.

Comment: Add Spring Security to your dependencies and simply configure it, nothing more, nothing less. No need to implement your own. As said the Spring Framework is something different as Spring Security (although related).

Comment: can you please tell guide me through the simple configuration, or the steps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41845/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-m-deinum)

Comment: I configured the spring security remember-me as per the discussion we had yesterday, and when the checkbox is clicked the cookie "spring_security_remember_me_cookie" is getting generated, however as soon as the session times out and i click on anything on the application the application gets redirected to the login page and the cookie is no more present when checked, this is defeating the whole purpose :(

Comment: Post your configuration.

Comment: key name was missing from the remembermeservices added it and got it working, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can simply be accomplished using the Spring security remember me authentication mechanism. What I did was made changes in the application-context-security.xml added the tag

```
<remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="vaib1q2w3e4r5tazsxdc"/>
```

and

```
<beans:bean id="rememberMeProcessingFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <beans:property name="key" value="vaib1q2w3e4r5tazsxdc" />
    <beans:property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="120"/>
    <beans:property name="alwaysRemember" value="false" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.providers.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
    <custom-authentication-provider />
    <beans:property name="key" value="vaib1q2w3e4r5tazsxdc" />
</beans:bean>
```

By adding the above a new cookie by the name 'SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE' would be created and would make things work like charm.

Thanks,
-V